# Wrap the table cell content at newline character

Tags: css

I have a string containing new line character. When i tried to bind it to table cell it is not wrapping  at new line character.
attached is the screenshot for the reference.
In console window it is showing correctly as per the expectation, same i want in table td tag

[image]

Comment: Use two separate
<div>hi</div>   <div>this is new line</div>  make sure they are with display:block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the string from a database, there are two ways to accomplish this:

To replace `\n`'s with html breaks:

```
echo str_replace("\n", "<br>", $string);
```

To see `\n`'s as they are:

```
echo '<pre>' . $string . '</pre>';
```

There are also a css solution, apply this rule to the container:

```
white-space:pre;
```

Comment: white-space:pre; Solved my issue <td style="white-space:pre;">{{ExtendedErrorMessage}}</td>

Answer (score 1):

`white-space: pre;` may be what you're looking for:

```css
td {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <td>Extended Error message</td>
    <td>Hi
this is new line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<td>Hi<br>this is new line</td>
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>This is First</td>
    <td>Hi<br>this is new line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or use `pre` tag :

```
<td>
    <pre>Hi
         this is new line
    </pre>
</td>
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>This is First</td><td><pre>Hi
   this is new line</pre></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

set each line in `div` if you want you can set `margin` to `left`

```css
.new-line{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>hi</div><div class="new-line">this is new line</div></td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```